# Flutter Riverpod: how to pass 3 arguments in family?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

i am trying to pass 3 aruguments to family of riverpod. i can only make 2 arugument but i want to make it 3.

here is what i am trying to archieved

```
final allEmployeeOfVenodrsOfaParticularVenderUser = FutureProvider.family<
    List<AllEmployeeOfVendorParticularVenUser>, String, String>(
  (ref, vendocode) {
    return ref
        .read(apiProvider)
        .getAllEmployeeOfaparticluarVendorUser(vendorCode: vendocode);
  },
);
```

using two arugument but i want to pass 3 arugment

Comment: Use a generated provider with multiple "family" arguments.  Docs are at riverpod.dev, or see: RiverPod 2.0 in a video overview and three easy lessons:

* https://youtu.be/tfB_dSJa9Oc
* https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-state-management-riverpod/
* https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-riverpod-generator/
* https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-riverpod-async-notifier/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the riverpod documentation you can't pass 3 arguments to the family,
But what you can do is pass 2 arguments but the second argument you can pass as Map<String, dynamic> or an Object(Model class).

You will find both of the examples below

**1)**

```
final allEmployeeOfVenodrsOfaParticularVenderUser = FutureProvider.family<
    List<AllEmployeeOfVendorParticularVenUser>, Map<String, dynamic>>(
  (ref, vendocode) {
    var arg1 = vendocode['arg1'];
    var arg2 = vendocode['arg2'];
    return ref
        .read(apiProvider)
        .getAllEmployeeOfaparticluarVendorUser(vendorCode: vendocode);
  },
);
```

**2)**

```
final allEmployeeOfVenodrsOfaParticularVenderUser = FutureProvider.family<
    List<AllEmployeeOfVendorParticularVenUser>, argsModel >(
  (ref, vendocode) {
    var arg1 = vendocode.arg1;
    var arg2 = vendocode.arg2;
    return ref
        .read(apiProvider)
        .getAllEmployeeOfaparticluarVendorUser(vendorCode: vendocode);
  },
);

@immutable
class argsModel extends Equatable {
  final String arg1;
  final String arg2;

  const argsModel(this. arg1, this. arg2);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [arg1, arg2];
}
```

Comment: It's actually a lot easier to use a generated provider for this, as it will let you pass the three args explicitly and generate all the proper classes behind the scenes.  It's amost magical.

Comment: what i even did was to combine it as stream and split it...

Comment: but you will surely work